# Usage message when using argparse.REMAINDER

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have a Python program that takes as its (only) positional command-line argument one or more file path expressions. I'm using argparse for the CL parsing, and `argparse.REMAINDER` for the variable that contains the file path(s). See code below:

```py
import argparse
import sys

# Create parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="My test program")

def parseCommandLine():
    # Add arguments
    parser.add_argument('filesIn',
                        action="store",
                        type=str,
                        nargs=argparse.REMAINDER,
                        help="input file(s)")

    # Parse arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return(args)

def main():
    # Get input from command line
    args = parseCommandLine()

    # Input files
    filesIn = args.filesIn

    # Print help message and exit if filesIn is empty
    if len(filesIn) == 0:
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit()

    # Do something
    print(filesIn)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now, when a user runs the script without any arguments, this results in the following help message:

```
usage: test.py [-h] ...
```

Where `...` represents the positional input. From a user's perspective it would be more informative if the name of the variable (`filesIn`) was displayed here instead. Especially because typing `test.py -h` results in this:

```
usage: test.py [-h] ...

My test program

positional arguments:
  filesIn     input file(s)
```

I.e. the usage line displays `...` but then in the list of positional arguments `filesIn` is used.

So my question is whether there's some easy way to change this (i.e. always display `filesIn`)?

Comment: The metavar is handy for changing the usage display, regardless of narg value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `argparse.REMAINDER` here. You are not gathering all remaining arguments, you are trying to take filenames.

Use `'+'` instead to capture all remaining arguments as filenames and you need at least one:

```
parser.add_argument('filesIn',
                    action="store",
                    type=str,
                    nargs='+',
                    help="input file(s)")
```

This produces better help output:

```
$ bin/python test.py 
usage: test.py [-h] filesIn [filesIn ...]
test.py: error: too few arguments
$ bin/python test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] filesIn [filesIn ...]

My test program

positional arguments:
  filesIn     input file(s)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Comment: This, however, doesn't solve the question as stated in the title. In my case I do want to use `argparse.REMAINDER`, and it gives the unhelpful usage message stated in the question.

Comment: @Jellby: the *point* of `argparse.REMAINDER` is to capture the remainder of the command line, including further optional switches, to be passed on to another parser later on. If you are not going to do that, don't use `argparse.REMAINDER`. If you *are* going to do that, tailor your `help` message towards that usecase and explain what is going on in that.

Comment: Indeed. By "unhelpful" I mean that the name appearing in the usage message is hardcoded to `...`, while the argument description uses the argument name. The best one can do is using `metavar='...'`, at least then the names agree. But I'd rather have something like `[extra_args]` in the usage message.

Comment: In the case of `command` and `arguments` you can disable the help text for `arguments` with `help=argparse.SUPPRESS` and play with the `command` metavar: `metavar="command [args ...]"`, semantically this may be seen as a hack but from the final user point of view it solves the problem.